# App won't run without google play services which are not by your device

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps

I have a problem with  GoogleMap on some devices(include some emulators and some real devices). When I try to load the map this error happens

> App won't run without google play services which are not by your
> device

, but the GoogleMap application shows its map on its own application. Is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should fall back your app to use [Open Street Map](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid) if the device is not supported Google Play service. The native google maps app use their own API so  it can run independently with Google Play Service

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I believe using osm will solve the problem but developers should consider that osm is not as good as GoogleMap.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can not use Google Maps Platform without Google Play Services. However there is a trick which you can show map with or without Google Play Services.

First determine device has Google Play Services (GPS). Following code works for that purpose:

```
   int resultCode = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
            if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
                 // Load Map as Native
                 // https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start
            }else{
                // Load Map in Webview/Customtabs
                // https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview
            }
```

If device has GPS and enabled, you can safely load native map. If doesn't you need to load map in [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) or [CustomTabs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/android/custom-tabs/overview/). By this way, you can cover all devices whether GPS is available or not. Best regards.

Note: In your situation, if you are using emulator you need to choose Android Platform with Google APIs.

Comment: thanks for your answer Aykut, does we have any access to google map APIs like location etc,  in second way?

Comment: Yes both Android and Javascript directly linked to Google Maps APIs